# Ruby AWS Cloud Search Gem for indexing and searching compound queries for api version 2013-01-01

Tags: ruby, amazon-cloudsearch

Anyone know of a good Ruby gem for Amazon Cloud Search?  With the following criteria:

1) Support for cloud search api version 2013-01-01

2) Supports queries with multiple constraints (ie. search movies with title starting with "star", and a rating of 5 or above, and was made before 1980, etc.)

3) Also supports indexing data to the search domain.

Note that I have already looked at all of these:

https://github.com/spokesoftware/aws_cloud_search - doesn't meet criteria 1

https://github.com/wellbredgrapefruit/asari - doesn't meet criteria 3

https://github.com/awslabs/cloudsearchable - doesn't meet criteria 1

https://github.com/willian/cloud_search - doesn't meet criteria 1 or 2

If there really isn't such a gem that meets all my criteria, I will write my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a gem for Cloud Search API 2013-01-01 with all the features I wanted:

https://github.com/stevenjl/rawscsi

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at the new aws-sdk-core-ruby gem from the AWS team?
https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-core-ruby

I am using it for communication with DynamoDB and S3, and it pairs really well with the services' APIs. Checkout the CloudSearch service in the docs: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/frames.html